# d3js zooming groups of circles

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying d3.js zoom behavior for the first time, I am quite struggling to get it worked. My requirement is to have a zoom in, zoom out behaviour in a svg element where browser's zoom behaviour should be disabled and only the circles inside the svg should increase/decrease its radius upon zoom in/out.

In summary, when the user scrolls the mouse the svg width, height should not change. Just the circles should change its radius.

This is what I have now, can anyone help me to fill it in?

```
<g>
    <circle id='top' cx="180" cy="120" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle id='top' cx="200" cy="220" r="30" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
</g>
<g>
    <circle id='top' cx="320" cy="150" r="50" style="stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px; fill:white"/>
</g>
```

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 8])
            .on("zoom", function () {

            console.log('zooming');

            var graph = d3.select('svg');

            graph
                .selectAll('g')
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");


        });



    var svg = d3.select('svg').append('g').call(zoom);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the zoom listener to the SVG instead of the new group.

Change following line of code

```
var svg = d3.select('svg').append('g').call(zoom);
```

To

```
var svg = d3.select('svg').call(zoom);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on("zoom", function() {    
    var graph = d3.select('svg');
    graph
      .selectAll('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  });
var svg = d3.select('svg').call(zoom);
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilsha/uxdozyvu/22/)

Comment: it works fine, but when I add a drag event to the circle it mess things up, I will add a fiddle.

Comment: In this following fiddle zoom works fine without drag, when I add the drag It applies the drag to all the group. http://jsfiddle.net/fawzan/6225w3j7/

Comment: I asked a seperate question on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915304/d3js-zoom-drag-causes-conflict

Comment: I have answered the question. :)