# D3: zoom fails to include elements as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to adjust my D3 zoom so that ALL elements zoom in as expected. My elements are as follows: countries, markers (circles) and flows (polygons).

So far, all elements load as expected. The countries first, then the circles and flows upon subsequent interaction. But the zoom only works for the countries. The circles and flows do not zoom but just stay static. What am I doing wrong?

Link to my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Lo2mjhjq/1/)

**Countries I add to map as follows:**

```
var country = g.append("g");

d3.json("countries.json", function(collection) {
  country.selectAll("path")
      .data(collection.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

**Circles I add after user interaction, as follows:**

```
var g_circles = svg.append("g").attr("class", "circles");

$.each(circles, function(i, d) {
  dz = projection(d);
  g_circles.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "marker")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("cx", dz[0])
    .attr("cy", dz[1])
    .call(zoom);
});
```

**Flows I add to the map as follows:**

```
  var g_lines = svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");

  g_lines.selectAll(".link_line")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link_line")
    .style('fill-opacity', 0.3)
    .attr("d", "path")
    .call(zoom);
```

**Zoom is as follows:**

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .translate(projection.translate())
  .scale(projection.scale())
  .scaleExtent([h, 350000 * h])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  svg.selectAll("path, circle, .link_line").attr("d", path);
}
```

Comment: please add simply working code, to make it easy to help

Comment: Sure, KEKUATAN. Please find my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Lo2mjhjq/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add all the expected groups (g_circles and g_lines) into a new single group (g) and use the dimensions of this group to do the focus?

Zoom should be applied to the SVG:

[See this other question as it's very similar to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901553/d3js-zooming-groups-of-circles)

Zooms are commonly expected to work as a translation of the svg [like in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/cpdean/7a71e687dd5a80f6fd57).

Comment: I have also tried to apply the zoom to the SVG as opposed to <g>.. results are exactly the same.

Comment: I've created the following fiddle, if that helps Edorka: https://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/Lo2mjhjq/1/

Comment: zoomed seems to redraw the paths instead of changing the translation of the svg.